# Send json data to SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, json, sql-server-2008, asp.net-web-api

I have this problem: I receive from client-side data as json in WebApi (C#) services. Data contain several data table as arrays of objects.

I need to make change in database within one transaction (according with data received from client side).

Which one is the best approach:

1. send data to T-SQL as json (as string), and there to parse json and transform in hierarchy table as in article: [Consuming JSON string in SQL](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/),

or

2. parse json in WebApi services, and then send to T-SQL one by one?

I think the first method is the right one.

Comment: I would start by doing a simple web / google search here is a good link to read as well https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d6481d7b-6981-4c3c-9701-988fdc887c48/load-json-type-data-to-sql-server?forum=transactsql

Comment: Linked article gets you the answer: TSQL isn’t really designed for doing complex string parsing, particularly where strings represent nested data structures such as XML, JSON, YAML, or XHTML.  Since you already have web service in mind, you really don't need to force TSQL into parsing JSON, right?

Comment: the problem is I think is better to do all data table operations in one Stored procedure  -in one transaction, otherwise I need to make multiple call so Sql server, which is not preffered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeeded to create stored procedure with parameter json string contain multiple data table.
It was simple to parse the Hierarchy table created with  parseJSON (see article [Consuming JSON string in SQL](https://www.simple-talk.com/content/article.aspx?article=1176)).
According with this, I think is a good way to send multiple data table to SQL.

I want to mention: I don't have any experience with SQL Server. So maybe the question is stupid (was negative voted), but for me wasn't...